# Does Arya Stark know how to make poisons outside of the House of Black and White?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After Arya Stark leaves the House of Black and White in *Game of Thrones* season 6, does she know how to access and/or make poisons?

Comment: @Skooba If there aren't any clues about it in currently available works, that's the answer to the question. "We don't know because...". I've got a funny feeling in the books there's a scene where she's identifying poison ingredients *and* mixing them by smell while blind, I could be wrong though

Comment: I want to know when she learned how to bake a pie.

Comment: In season 7 she poisons the Freys, so yes, she can utilize poisons outside of the House of Black and White.

Answer (score 4):

It is **likely** she knows how to mix poisons.

In [Ayra's training scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBue47iGonM) during S6E3, we see her smelling some ingredients and she is able to tell aparently determine what they are by smell alone (0:55 to 1:09). We cut away from that scene but come back to it and see her mixing the ingredients into a bottle (1:44 to 1:46, 1:53 to 1:58, 2:01 to 2:04).

However, we do not *fully* know what these ingredients are or what they are making. We can *speculate* that it is poison...

Comment: Well, given that we later see her recognise poison by smell alone in a similar way, she's probably not mixing aftershave or Uncle Benjen's famous cajun marinade...

Comment: I thought it was ingredients for that pie she made... it hard hard to mask the "big toe" taste (or was it thumb?) either, you need some good cooking skills!

Comment: @user568458, that recipe is safely stored in the crypts of Winterfell <shhhhh>